# React arrange child div orders, according to the props from the parent component

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am using react for my project and inside it, I have a child component where there are more divs,
**I take 4 divs for example now**,

**Example:**
child component:

```
`       <div className="main-div">
      <div className="one">
          <h1>React is crazy, but I love it.</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="two">
          <img src="./some-image.jpg" alt="" />
          <h2>Some content related to two</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="three">
          <div>
              <div>
                  <div>Dummy content</div>
                  <div>More dummy content</div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div className="four">
          <div>
              <p>Some content related to four</p>
              <p>some dummy content</p>
              <h1>Hello guys</h1>
          </div>
      </div>
     </div>`
```

according to the props from the parent component , I need to fit them in the order , for example if the parent props has [two, four, one , three ] means I need to arrange the divs has

```
`<div className="main-div">
      <div className="two">
          <img src="./some-image.jpg" alt="" />
          <h2>Some content related to two</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="four">
          <div>
              <p>Some content related to four</p>
              <p>some dummy content</p>
              <h1>Hello guys</h1>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div className="one">
          <h1>React is crazy, but I love it.</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="three">
          <div>
              <div>
                  <div>Dummy content</div>
                  <div>More dummy content</div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

   </div>`
```

I want the div to be arranged according to the props and class name matches ,is there any way to achieve it?

By using any new plugin or only with plain react is also fine for my requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy to achieve using the map in js.
A very easy solution can be

```
const Parent = (props) => {
  return props.data.map((val) => {
    if (val === "one") {
      return (
        <div className="one">
          <h1>React is crazy, but I love it.</h1>
        </div>
      );
    }
    if (val === "two") {
      return (
        <div className="two">
          <img src="./some-image.jpg" alt="" />
          <h2>Some content related to two</h2>
        </div>
      );
    }
    ... and so on
  });
};
```

This way the divs will map according to the order coming from the props data.
You can also use `switch case` instead of if else, that will work too.